# Go from Permutation Indices to Permutation Matrix in Python

Tags: python, numpy, permutation

I have two lists of indices. I would like to generate the relevant permutation matrix. The two lists have equal size n and have all integers from 0 up to n-1.

**Simple Example**:

Given initial and final indices (as per the two-line convention https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix):

```
initial_index = [3,0,2,1] and final_index = [0,1,3,2]
```

In other words, the last entry (3) has got to go to the first (0), the first (0) has got to go to the second (1) etc. You could also imagine zipping these two lists in order to obtain the permutation rules: [(3,0),(0,1),(2,3),(1,2)], read this as (3 -> 0),(0 -> 1) and so forth. This is a right-shift for a list, or a down-shift for a column vector. The resulting permutation matrix should be the following:

```
M = [[0,0,0,1],
     [1,0,0,0],
     [0,1,0,0],
     [0,0,1,0]]
```

Multiplying this matrix by a column vector indeed shifts the entries down by 1, as required.

*Are there any relevant operations that could achieve this efficiently?*

Comment: ```np.roll(np.eye(4, dtype=np.int32), -1, axis=-1)``` will generate this particular permutation matrix.

Comment: Unfortunately I have a vector that is about 1000 entries long. I don't think your method will do the trick.

Comment: What do you want exactly: generate the (only) matrix or save a way to apply the permutation? You do not need a permutation matrix (possibly of size 1000x1000) for the latter.

Comment: I need the permutation matrix

Comment: Ok. For the example, the matrix does not match with the input/output. It seems the values are not just shifted. Is the example correct?

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you want to permute the identity matrix row by row according to `initial_index` and then permute the result column by column according to `final_index`?

Comment: Yes, the index pairs are correct. If you were to zip the two lists you would get the input/output pairs of indices. E.g. (3 -> 0), (0 -> 1)... Look at the two-line convention of permutations https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix

Comment: Initial_index and final_index are not the input/output, they are the indices of the input/output due to permutation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want an n-by-n matrix where, for every i from 0 to n-1, the cell at row `final_index[i]` and column `initial_index[i]` is set to 1, and every other cell is set to 0.

NumPy advanced indexing can be used to set those cells easily:

```
permutation_matrix = numpy.zeros((n, n), dtype=int)

permutation_matrix[final_index, initial_index] = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to the good answer of @user2357112, you can use sparse matrices to be efficient in memory:

```py
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

permutation_matrix = csr_matrix((np.ones(n, dtype=int), (final_index, initial_index)), shape=(n,n))

# Use permutation_matrix.todense() to convert the matrix if needed
```

The complexity of building this sparse matrix is `O(n)` in both time and space while for dense matrices it is `O(n^2)`. So they are much better for big vectors (>1000).